# Не запускается код по скачиванию файлов в GUI режиме

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, download

Вот фрагмент кода моей программы по скачиванию файлов. Я использую GUI Tkinter.
Проблемы начинаются когда `radio_choise.get() == 1`.

Программа работает корректно только со строчкой:

> urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'video.mp4')

и отказывается работать с кодом как в пимере ниже
(фрагмент от `chunk_size = 1024` до `f.flush()`)

Выдает except. Хотя отдельно от программы этот код работает хорошо. Как решить эту проблему (если это проблема).

И я не понимаю почему так. Пожалуйста подскажите.

```
path = 'C:\Users\username\Desktop'
url = 'https://d1p9dpblu12ati.cloudfront.net/allerhande/media/2015/12/07/asset-1449505886026230.mp4'

try:
    if radio_choise.get() == 0:
        path_nice = ''
        for sym in path:
            if sym == '/' or '\\':
                sym.replace(sym, '\\\\')
                path_nice += str(sym)
            else:
                path_nice = str(path)
        YouTube(url).streams.first().download(str(path_nice))


    elif radio_choise.get() == 1:
        # urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'video.mp4')

        chunk_size = 1024
        file_name = 'video.mp4'
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
            total_length = int(r.headers.get('content-length'))
            for data in tqdm(iterable=r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size), total=total_length/chunk_size, unit='KB'):
                f.write(data)
                f.flush()

except:
    messagebox.showerror('Error!', 'Path or URL is incorrect.')
```

Comment: Сделайте печать что за исключение срабатывает, и добавьте в вопрос

Comment: Которое я сам прописал: 
except:
    messagebox.showerror('Error!', 'Path or URL is incorrect.'). Других ошибок нет.

Comment: Так правильно, вы просто игнорируете тип исключения, и любое исключение, которое происходит в коде, считаете ошибкой пути или URL. Сделайте вывод информации об исключении через `print(sys.exc_info()[0])`, как показано здесь: [Handling exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), и посмотрите что будет писать в консоль.

Comment: Не в исключении дело точно. Результат выполнение кода один и тот же: файл создается, видео скачивается ровно 243 байта из 986(в данном случае). Думаю, что-то не дописываю в коде..

Comment: Первое что нужно исправить (независимо от того, возникают ли у вас исключения при скачивании или нет) - сделать нормальную обработку исключений. Сейчас тип исключения тупо игнорируется - это грубая ошибка многих новичков. Представьте, что вы приходите к врачу, и независимо от ваших симптомов (кашель, или сыпь, или острая боль в правом боку) говорит - "наверное комар укусил, помажьте йодом". Как сделать - я вам дал ссылку выше. Пока вы не приведете полный текст исключения с трейсбеком, нельзя говорить что "Не в исключении дело точно".

Comment: Второе - если файл создается одинакового небольшого размера, можно попробовать открыть его текстовым редактором, возможно сервер вернул вам ошибку в текстовом виде.